# Reverse letters of a word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, function, reverse

If there is a sentence like "HI my name is jack", how can I change it to "ih ym eman si kcaj" ?

The order is the same but the letters are reversed. it must be a function.

```
  var sentence = "HI my name is jack";

function reverser(){
var reversed = sentence.split().reverse().join();
document.write(reversed);
}
```

Comment: What you did reverses the whole string. First split by words, then loop, reverse each word, and join back the string.

Comment: Sounds like homework. If you're having specific trouble, you should ask about it. I see a few issues with the code, but you should explain the problem for yourself.

Comment: @elclanrs yh i noticed. Can you show me how to split each word, i think i need a stack for saving each word right ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+how+to+split+sentence+into+words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
function reverser(inputSentence){
    var words = inputSentence.split(" "); // Split the sentence into words
    var output = new Array(); // Initiate the output
    words.forEach(function(word) { // For each word
        output.push(word.split("").reverse().join("")); // Reverse the word and add it to the output
    });
    return output.join(" "); // Join output to string and return it
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fRj4B/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the entire sentence into words, iterate through the list of words, and reverse each word individually. Then, you need to join the entire thing back together to get the final sentence.

```
function reverse(sentence) {
    var reversed = [];
    sentence.split(' ').forEach(function (word) {
        reversed.push(word.split('').reverse().join(''));
    });
    return reversed.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence.split(' ').map(function(str) { return str.split("").reverse().join(""); }).join(' ');
```

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm mostly just trying to figure out how to do this without explicitly defining any new / anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sentance = "HI my name is jack";
alert(sentance.split("").reverse().join("").split(" ").reverse().join(" "));
```